# Регулярное выражение не работает

Tags: c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Нужно из HTML кода выдернуть содержимое тега.
Но в Match ничего не приходит. Регулярное выражение рабоче - проверял в сторонних отладчиках. В чём может быть проблема

```
string output = "<div><img alt=\"\" src=\"/source/\" height=\"60\"/></div>";
var regex = new Regex("/(?<=<img alt=\"\" src=\")(.*)(?=\" height=\"60\")/g");
Match match = regex.Match(output);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не стоит разбирать HTML при помощи регулярных выражений. Воспользуйтесь HTML-парсерами типа [CsQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery/) или [AngleSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngleSharp).

Пример того, как получить то-же самое на AngleSharp:

```csharp
var html = "<div><img alt=\"\" src=\"/source/\" height=\"60\"/></div>";

var document = new HtmlParser(html).Parse();
var imgSrc = document.QuerySelector("img").GetAttribute("src");
```

В основе - обычные CSS-селекторы, как при использовании jQuery. Такой код проще составить, его проще читать, он выдает гораздо более предсказуемый результат, и на вытаскивание нужной информации затрачивается в разы меньше ресурсов, нежели при использовании регулярных выражений.